# Wordpress PHP Error after modifications in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I was making modifications in functions.php which is generally in Appearances/Edit of wordpress dashboard. As soon as I made the changes and updated the file, the website crashed: now it shows a lame white dead page with some syntax error codes. I do not have access to admin panel / wp-admin. It would work to erase all those wordpress data base and restart, but it means a lot more work. What should I do now?

Comment: just delete your last editions and upload the file again

Comment: just check the functions.php file, is there any whitespace?

Comment: @Yahya ..Iam not having access to admim panel....does it works through cpanel?

Comment: @Bhumi ....Iam not having access to /wp-admin.

Comment: use your ftp account to access your website files, or use file explorer in the cpanel account

Comment: Sure..Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Its better to do edit with FTP